# Solving implicit equations in R

Tags: implicit-function

I have an equation which looks like this:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{}}=−2\log⁡\left(+\frac{}{\sqrt{}}\right)$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants

How do I solve this in $\mathbb{R}$?
Can this be solved iteratively?

Answer (score 1):

First, recall that under the substitution $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ ($y>0$), you obtain the equivalent equation
$$
y=-2\log(A+By).
$$

Up to some simplifications, you can also realize that the solution of the above is equivalent to find the zeros of the function $$g(y)=e^{-\frac{y}{2}}-A-By.$$

The above equation is non-linear so that there is not direct available on the literature that gives you a direct solution. In any case, you can use the so-called "perturbation of the inverse approach" (fixed point theorem in disguise) to prove for which $A \& B$, you have a solution (I will come back to this later, depending on your reply).

A simple strategy is try to apply recursively the Bolzano theorem. For this approach, under the fact that your function is continuous, you only need to start with a first estimate for the interval $[a,b]$ for which $g(a)g(b)<0$.

Maybe it would be nice that you tell me in which course this problem have appeared to provide you a goal-oriented answer to your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to find out the values of for 30 different values of A and a same constant 30 values of B. The values of A are: A<-[1] 2.620757e-05 1.310379e-05 8.735857e-06 6.551893e-06 5.241514e-06 4.367929e-06
 [7] 3.743939e-06 3.275946e-06 2.911952e-06 2.620757e-06 2.382506e-06 2.183964e-06
[13] 2.015967e-06 1.871969e-06 1.747171e-06 1.637973e-06 1.541622e-06 1.455976e-06
[19] 1.379346e-06 1.310379e-06 1.247980e-06 1.191253e-06 1.139460e-06 1.091982e-06
[25] 1.048303e-06 1.007984e-06 9.706508e-07 9.359847e-07 9.037094e-07 8.735857e-07. The value of B is 0.0004864867

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the Colebrook equation for the friction factor in a pipe.

First, let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{}}=t$ to make the equation
$$t=-2\log(A+Bt)$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$t=2 W\left(\pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{e^{A/B}}{B^2}}\right)-\frac{A}{B}$$

Take care that, in the real domain, $W(y)$ is real if $y \geq -\frac 1 e$ and that two branches $(W_0(y)\text{ and } W_{-1}(y))$ exist.